# How to implement a Role Play Dimension into Data Vault

Tags: data-modeling, star-schema, data-vault

I have a data model based on a star schema. It stores three date elements. I integrated them into one role play dimension to avoid redundant dates. I would like to store my data into a data vault model in the core DWH and show the star schema as a view. But right now, im not sure how to handle the problem with the role play model. Should I implement three separate Hubs and Sats fpr the dates? and put them together in the View Layer? or can i implement one date hub + sat and reference them to the link table three times (to the three different dates)?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I consider the dates as reference table. I have draw a logical model If i understood your problem correctly, Then next logical model would be a possible solution on how to use the same in Hub satelitte or link satellite.

A Role playing Dimension or you could have 3 views on this dimension :

[image: Problem]

Solution :

[image: Soution]

Note: This is logical model, So "NO" physical foreign keys.

> Dan's Definition of "Reference tables" are referenced from Satellites, but never bound with physical foreign keys. There is no prescribed structure for reference tables: use what works best in your specific case, ranging from simple lookup tables to small data vaults or even stars. They can be historical or have no history, but it is recommended that you stick to the natural keys and not create surrogate keys in that case.[20] Normally, data vaults have a lot of reference tables, just like any other Data Warehouse.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling#Reference_tables